# HTTP/1.0 server in C, how to send big files to the client?

Tags: c, file, http, server

I have to write (as an assignment) a small HTTP/1.0 server in C.

Here's my issue: I don't know how to handle the case where the page requested by the client has a very large size.

I thought that it would be better to first read the whole file, and then start sending the reply (including status line and headers) to the client, the main reason being that I can set the status code appropriately. For instance, say that while the server has already read and stored as a string half of the file the client wants, `read()` fails. I would then go on and set "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal server error" as the status line.

The problem with this approach is that it takes too much memory if the file is big (and since every connection is handled by a separate thread, if multiple threads were to store files of considerable dimensions as a string the memory usage would grow even worse).

As a solution I thought about opening the file, sending the status line and the headers, then read into a buffer a given amount (not too large) of bytes and iteratively send what is in the buffer until I've read/sent the whole file.

This solves the problem, but again, what if `read()` fails while I'm halfway through the file? The client request could not be fulfilled because of an internal error, thus a 500 status code would be appropriate, but I've already sent a 200 OK message through the socket!

How is this issue normally handled in HTTP servers?

Comment: Which error do you expect `read()` to encounter after you have already successfully called `read()` on the same file? The only one I can see happening in practice is `EINTR`, which is harmless. Also, depending on your platform, you may have better options like `sendfile()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As a solution I thought about opening the file, sending the status line and the headers, then read into a buffer a given amount (not too large) of bytes and iteratively send what is in the buffer until I've read/sent the whole file.

That is exactly what you should be doing.  Query the file size beforehand so you can put it in the `Content-Length` response header, and then stop your read+send loop when you have sent that many bytes.

If you can switch to HTTP 1.1, you have another option.  You can omit the `Content-Length` header and instead send a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, and then you can send each buffer in `chunked` format (see [RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)), where each chunk specifies its own byte size.  The data transfer is terminated by sending a 0-length chunk.  This allows you to send/stream large amounts of data without knowing the total size up front.  But this option is not available in HTTP 1.0.

> This solves the problem, but again, what if read() fails while I'm halfway through the file?

The only thing you can do is close the socket to signal the transfer is terminated.  If you send a `Content-Length` header (or in the case of HTTP 1.1 chunking, send a 0-length chunk), the client will know when it has received the proper end of file, and a premature closure is an error.  But without that information, a socket closure is the only way to signal the end of the transfer, and there would be no way for the client to know if it was successful or erroneous (HTTP 1.1 does have the ability to resume broken downloads, but HTTP 1.0 does not).

> The client request could not be fulfilled because of an internal error, thus a 500 status code would be appropriate, but I've already sent a 200 OK message through the socket!

You can't change the response status once you have sent it.  But if you let the client know how it can detect the proper end of file, it will know how to detect a broken download.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!